# Data is not getting displayed in PieChart of HighCharts using Angularjs (Dynamic Data from Ajax call)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I am trying to make pie chart in Angularjs using highcharts. The chart is not displaying data.It will show hardcoded data (where it is marked in the code) but doesn't show dynamic data in json format.

My Html template

```
 <div style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top:100px;">
 <hc-pie-chart  title="Employee from diffrent states" data="pieData">Placeholder for pie chart</hc-pie-chart></div>
```

My Controller and Directive

```
 app.directive(
                'hcPieChart',
                function() {
                    return {
                        restrict : 'E',
                        template : '<div></div>',
                        scope : {
                            title : '@',
                            data : '='
                        },
                        link : function(scope, element) {
                            Highcharts
                                    .chart(
                                            element[0],
                                            {
                                                chart : {
                                                    type : 'pie'
                                                },
                                                title : {
                                                    text : scope.title
                                                },
                                                plotOptions : {
                                                    pie : {
                                                        allowPointSelect : true,
                                                        cursor : 'pointer',
                                                        dataLabels : {
                                                            enabled : true,
                                                            format : '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                series : [ {
                                                    data : scope.data
                                                } ]
                                            });
                        }
                    };
                })

app.controller("highChartController", function($scope,$state, $window,$timeout,$stateParams,chartService)   
    StateList();

        function StateList() {
         var getData=chartService.getStateList()
         getData.then(function(emp) {           
            var data= emp.data; 
            $scope.pieData=data;        //if i will put hardcoded data here it will not work
        });
         //if i will put hardcoded data here it will work
    }
});
```

My json file

```
var data=[{name: "Bihar", y: 1},{name: "Karnataka", y: 3},{name: "Bengal", y: 2},{name: "Punjab", y: 3},{name: "Maharastra", y: 2}]
```

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in an online code editor?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it myself. I just needed to add this code in the directive to so it will redraw the chart.

```
scope.$watch("data", function (newValue) {
                                chart.series[0].setData(newValue, true);
                              }, true);
```

```
app.directive(
                'hcPieChart',
                function(chartService) {
                    return {
                        restrict : 'E',
                        template : '<div></div>',
                        scope : {
                            title : '@',
                            data : '='
                        },
                        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                              console.log(2);

                            },
                            template: '<div id="container" style="margin: 0 auto">not working</div>',
                        link : function(scope, element,attr) {

                              var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                                chart: {
                                  renderTo: 'container',
                                  plotBackgroundColor: null,
                                  plotBorderWidth: null,
                                  plotShadow: false
                                },
                                title: {
                                    text: scope.title
                                },
                                plotOptions: {
                                    pie: {
                                      allowPointSelect: true,
                                      cursor: 'pointer',
                                      dataLabels: {
                                        enabled: true,
                                        color: '#000000',
                                        connectorColor: '#000000',
                                        formatter: function () {
                                          return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.percentage + ' %';
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                },
                                series: [{
                                  type: 'pie',
                                  data: scope.data
                                }]
                              });
                            scope.$watch("data", function (newValue) {
                                chart.series[0].setData(newValue, true);
                              }, true);

                        }
                    };
                })
```